# Firefox keeps returning ajax status as error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox

I have an ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
        url: webURL,
        type: 'post',
        data: somedata,
        cache: false,
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: successFunc,
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
               {
                   console.log("Status: " + textStatus);
                   console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
                   alert("Some error!")
               }
    });
```

This request on the server actually executes a long running query to a database ( takes about ten minutes ).

But, this request returns within about 3-5 minutes and keeps showing that alert of "Some error!". On the server though, the database query is still running and never returned! This happens only on Firefox. It works fine on Chrome. The textStatus field returns "error" and errorThrown is blank.

Can anyone help me with why this ajax request returns before the server even sends a response?

**This happens only on Firefox and with long running requests that take more than 6-7 minutes to return.**

I have a related question. I see that Firefox keeps retrying the ajax requests after a few minutes. So my code checks whether the request is already present in the cache. If it is, then the cache just keeps getting polled until the result of the query is also in the cache. The thing is, if Firefox is retrying a request, how is this going to impact the request? Will there be multiple requests waiting on the cache or will there be a single request at a time and the old connection keeps getting closed?

Comment: what are u assigning to somedata?

Comment: Ensure you're providing valid json data in the somedata variable - as above, could you give us an example input/output please?

Comment: somedata is the result of a form. 
So input: {query1: [{name: xyz, value:abc}, {name:qwerty, value:abcd}]}
output: is actually a list of objects, returned by Django using json.dumps:
HttpResponse(json.dumps(cache_result), mimetype='application/json')

This works on Chrome so I am not sure if the data is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this code....

```
 $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "Default.aspx/sayHello",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              data: "{}",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(response)
              {
                alert(response.d);
              },
              error: function(response)
              {
                alert(response.status);
              }
          });
```

Comment: no, it still went to the fail case about 5-6 minutes after the request was started, the database query is still running so it didn't really return and textStatus is still "Error"

Comment: The  response text comes back as blank. Not sure why though, since the same thing works on Chrome. Also, refreshing the page on Firefox works since I have my results in a cache on the backend. I strongly suspect something to be timing out. I just can't see what

Comment: Also, I didn't use the exact code you gave since I need to make a POST request

Comment: I don't know what the error is. The issue is NOT with the request itself. The problem is that I'm getting a blank response before the actual response is being sent

Comment: yes, that's exactly the same thing I've been trying except I have a cache:false field as well

Comment: I'm sorry, it didn't. Firefox seems to cancel the ajax request after a certain time. I handled it by adding retry logic in the error handler